# CSS media:print - Crop images to page size

Tags: css, printing

I have a set of images, which are full-page screenshots of web pages. They may be very tall.

I want to create an HTML page containing those images, for the purpose of printing out those screenshots.

I want a maximum of one screenshot to appear per printed page. The width of each image should be fixed.

If the image is taller than the printed page, it should be cropped so that only the the top-most region of the screenshot appears. The region discarded by the crop should not be printed at all (i.e. no image should span multiple printed pages).

Is this possible to do with CSS?

Comment: Give the image a size of `width` and `height` in print units, and then use `object-fit: 100% auto; object-position: 0 0;`?